# Call on Success of useQuery Custom hooks inside React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, callback, react-hooks

I have a custom hook in a separate folder which is a useQUery hook.

```
export default function useFetchProfile(userId) {
  console.log("fetching profile");
  return useQuery(`profileInfo`, () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      try {
xxxxxxxxx

}
```

I use this hook inside a react component and call the onSuccess function as follows.

```
const {
    data: profileUser,
    isLoading: isLoadingUser,
    refetch: refetchUser,
  } = useFetchProfile(props.match.params.userId, {
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log("success");
    },
    onError: (err) => {},
  });
```

The onSuccess is not being called. However if i call the onSuccess inside the hook folder, it works.
I need to call the onSucess inside the component itself.
Any idea what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually pass the config object to `useQuery`:

```
// add config object to custom hook
export default function useFetchProfile(userId, config) {
  return useQuery(`profileInfo`, () => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      // use config.onSuccess / config.onError
    });
  });
}
```